# I can't close a dialog box when I using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I'm using Selenium to collect data when a message window pops up, this window is just a manual so I want to turn it off. I have tried many ways like: `find element by id`, `xpath`,... it doesn't work, or even switch to alert doesn't work. Below is the html screenshot of the website.

I appreciate all of your guidance.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGqRE.png)

Comment: Hi! if the data is below that dialog can't you just ignore it? or need to close it to load the contents below it?

Comment: What have you tried till now. What is the error you get?

Comment: hi i have to close the dialog box, i can download the data but i don't know how to close this dialog box. i just automatically press the x . button

Comment: Please provide your python snippet and error log for more clarity, based on which we can try to help

Comment: @SonLe : Is the url public ?

Answer (score 0):

As per the screen shot, `span` tag has `class` with `close-btn`. I am GUESSING that clicking on that `Element` would close the pop-up. Try below lines once. Have also applied `Explicit Waits` incase if the pop-up takes time to load.

```
#imports required:
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

wait = WebDriverWait(driver,30)
#Trial 1:
#driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='modal=dialog']//span[conatins(@class,'close-btn')]").click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='modal=dialog']//span[conatins(@class,'close-btn')]"))).click()
# Can also use `ends-with` instead of `contains` in the xpath.

#Trial -2
#driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@role='dialog']//span(contains(@class,'close-btn'))").click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[@role='dialog']//span(contains(@class,'close-btn'))"))).click()
```